# Set value to radio button group inside controller AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, controller, radio-button

```
<div ng-repeat="type in (prepopulatingFieldData|prepopulateValue:'480edd03-cf94-e411-bd87-00155d005107')" >

<input id="applicationType" name="applicationType" ng-model="formData.applicationType" type="radio" ng-value="{{type.Name}}">

</input>
```

I want to set a value when the page load inside my angular controller. But the problem is when I set value inside it gives an exceptionlike this

> Syntax Error: Token 'Member' is an unexpected token at column 9 of the expression [Student Member] starting at [Member].

My radio button values are

> Student Member,
>    Limited Member,
>    Member
>   can any one help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the problem is with ng-value. By using value instead of ng-value it worked well.. Thanks for the efforts you guys made.

Answer (score 1):

You should use ng-value but not use the {{}} for evaluation.

Also - you don't need to provider "id" property when working with angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use brackets within the ng-value directive, it will throw the error you get. Try it without the brackets and it should work.